# Accessing older Bing imagery in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, bing-maps

I've been using the Bing basemaps in ArcGIS 10. I'm studying bird ecology and have been overlaying bird GPS locations on to Bing imagery to see where the birds go and what habitats they chose.

The Bing imagery has been super clear, however, Bing has just recently updated the imagery for my study location in New Zealand and now the imagery is very dark and almost unusable.

I was wondering if there is a way to access previous Bing imagery? I previously downloaded the Bing aerial layer but this has automatically updated to the newer images too.

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to access the previous imagery unless someone has mirrored and archived Bing's tiles (which would likely be illegal). You may need to purchase imagery from a provider who maintain their own archive. I believe [MapData Services](http://mapdataservices.com/mapping-data-imagery) covers New Zealand

Answer (score 2):

It is currently not possible to access older Bing imagery within ArcMap 10 basemap layers.