# Bing shifted basemap imagery?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, editing, imagery

**Background:**
 Two years ago I used QGIS to digitize thousands of Alaskan stream segments using  Bing imagery as the basemap, via the Quick Map Services plugin.  The detailed Bing imagery allowed me to trace the streams at a scale of 1:5,000.  The stream CRS was identical to Bing (WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator, EPSG: 3857).  I was pleased with the results, as was my client.

**The problem:**  Since then, Bing updated their imagery for a large portion of my project area.  The new imagery is consistently shifted 5 - 6 meters to the east of the previous imagery.

As a result, my digitized streams (still in EPSG: 3857) no longer align with the new imagery, as seen below:

[image]

Here's another scene that depicts the mess that I now face.  The client expects the streams to align with the imagery, and I'm going to have to eat the $$$ required to fix this:

[image]

**Solution:**  I would be happy to somehow "roll back" the imagery to the earlier date so that it once again matches my stream lines.   However, previous SE posts ([Accessing older Bing imagery in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33455) and [How to avoid the ESRI basemap (Bing imagery) to update?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123073)) state that this is not possible.  I now plan to  select the streams within the offset area and apply rubbersheeting and/or manually move them. This is going to be a lot of work, and I'm not happy.

**My question:**

Before I start this big editing process, how do I know which imagery is spatially correct?

When I initially digitized the streams, I trusted the Bing imagery's location.  But now I don't know what to believe; is the new imagery incorrectly offset, or is the older imagery at fault?

Perhaps both are incorrect!

**Most importantly**, what happens if (when) the *next* imagery update does not align; am I doomed to continually "chase" the imagery by applying edits to the stream locations?

Comment: You need good and verified ground control points. When I was using BING or Google maps, I've had the luxury to send surveyor on the site and check important points so I could compare it later. I don't know is it possible in your case but other possible options will be to find some high-resolution imagery for that area or just a small part so you could visually identify some ground control points on it and compare it with a  position on BING maps.

Comment: I have seen this with ArcGIS basemaps. The fix was to apply a CRS transformation in the data frame, although I am not sure if this is possible with QGIS. If the imagery did indeed have error associated with it, I would consider georeferencing the streams to verifiably accurate imagery. Should be a quick fix.