# Location accuracy when mapping to basemap?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcmap, gps, basemap

I'm using ArcMap 10.6. My feature classes are in a NAD 1983 California State Plane Coordinate System. My basemap is Esri World Imagery WGS1984 World Mercator Auxiliary Sphere. I take field GPS collections with ArcGIS Collector in WGS1984, project them to NAD 1983, and then map my facilities on top of the basemap. I use the basemap imagery quite a bit as reference points for alignment of pipeline or structures. This is the workflow that I inherited when I started this job.

Is this workflow flawed? If so, what would be the best way to change the workflow going forward?

Comment: Don't entirely understand what you are doing here, are you using the imagery to adjust your GPS data? The ESRI imagery likely has a RMSE of +/- 15m and then there is all that "on the fly projection" stuff going on so, who know what the cumulative horizontal error is. If you are in the US, I would highly recommend using the USDA NAIP imagery. It is much more recent, has much higher accuracy, and you can either use it as an image service or download MrSID images.

Comment: Yeah, I was taught that we just need the facilities to line up with where it is on the basemap. Not the exact location, but where to find it in the field based on the basemap. I'll look into the NAIP imagery as a basemap.

Comment: Interesting question!  Here's a related issue to consider:  what happens when the basemap imagery that you've been relying on as an alignment reference (aka it is "the truth") shifts(!) with a new imagery release?  I suffered such a setback several years ago: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269668/bing-shifted-basemap-imagery  Was the original imagery correct, or was the new imagery correct?  I dunno...  In your situation, if your field methods and equipment are carefully controlled, one could argue that the collected data is closer to "the truth", rather than the basemap imagery.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans Your comment has me curious about using NAIP as background reference imagery, and I plan to look into it.  Can you point me to the documentation that led to your statement that it "...has much higher accuracy..."?  Also, where did you find the +/- 15m RMSE citation for ESRI basemaps?  Thanks.